# Grails Dynamic Form Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, dynamicform

I want to do something like below using Grails:

I can achieve the simple text field using jquery/js. However I need to add the dynamic form field for dropdown list and use Grails gsp tag. But I can't put something like:

```
var line = "<g:select/>";
```

in the javascript to add a row. Because there i no GSP engine for javascript.

Also for deleting a row, there is no id in my project, so not quite sure how to delete a row using dynamic form fields.

[image]

Comment: You want to add select using javascript, right?

Comment: No clear, add more details, what do you want.

Comment: Whatever, jquery/js or grails gsp. Just want a good solution. user1791574

Comment: Just implement the screenshot features using grails or jquery.

Comment: I have the same requirement - to create a dynamic form in grails which has various dynamically created input boxes. BAsically, I need a way to construct a form in grails at runtime, which then submits its params to a controller just like a form created at compile time.  Any ideas?